# How to get the second level of information in a REST API?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm new to react-native and I would like to create a Pokedex application.

To make it easy, I would like to have all the necessary informations on Pokemons in a single JSON file.

I use a while loop to call the REST API that contains almost all the information I need.

The objective is to fill up this JSON template with the API answers

```
{
    "id_pokemon": "1",
    "image": "./Images/pokemon/img/002.png",
    "icon": "./Images/pokemon/ico/002.ico",
    "name": "Slamèche",
    "type": {
        "0" :"feu" //=id_attack??
    },
    "stats":{
        "pv":"39",
        "att":"39",
        "def": "39",
        "satt": "39",
        "sdef": "39",
        "vit": "39"
    },
    "weakness": {
        "":"",
        "":"",
        "":"",
        "":"",
        "":"",
        "":"",
        "":"",
        "":"",
        "":"",
        "":"",
        "":"",
        "":"",
        "":"",
        "":"",
        "":"",
        "":"",
        "":"",
        "":""
    },
    "talent":{
        "0": "id_talent", //Brasier
        "1": "id_talent" //Force soleil - Talent caché
    },
    "caract": {
        "masse": "10",
        "capture_rate": "45",
        "generation": "1",
        "egg_group": {
            "0": "id_egg_group", //Draconique
            "1": "id_egg_group" //Monstrueuse
        },
        "mf_rate":"45", //45% de male donc (1-mf_rate)% de femelle
        "eff_point": {
            "stat": "att",
            "value": "3"
        },
        "poke_familly": "id_familly",
        "xp_10": "1000000"
    },
    "evolution":{
        "howto": "Manière d'évoluer",
        "to":{
            "0": "id_pokemon",
            "1": "id_pokemon"
        }
    },
    "lieu":{
        "0": {
            "name": "name",
            "precision": "Dans l'eau avec surf",
            "rate": "rare"
        }, 
        "1": {
            "name": "name",
            "precision": "Dans l'eau avec surf",
            "rate": "rare"
        } 
    },
    "attaque":{
        "0": "id_att",
        "1": "id_att",
        "2": "id_att"
    },
    "qr_code": "./Images/pokemon/qr_code/002.png"
}
```

To complete this, I tried to build a script in javascipt that I put here.

```
function getPokemon() {
    let i = 1


    while (i < 5){

        let url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/" + i

    $.get (url, callBackSucces).done(function() {

    })
    .fail(function() {
        alert("error");
    })
    .always(function() {

    })
    i++
};

    console.log(i)
}


var callBackSucces = function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    var pokemon = 
        {
            "id_pokemon": data.id,
            "image": "./Images/pokemon/img/002.png",
            "icon": "./Images/pokemon/ico/002.ico",
            "name": data.name,
            "type": {
                "type1": data.types[0].type.name,
                "type2": data.types[1].type.name
            },
            "stats": {
                "pv":data.stats[5].base_stat,
                "att": data.stats[4].base_stat,
                "def": data.stats[3].base_stat,
                "satt": data.stats[2].base_stat,
                "sdef": data.stats[1].base_stat,
                "vit": data.stats[0].base_stat
            },
            "weakness": {
                "":"",
                "":"",
                "":"",
                "":"",
                "":"",
                "":"",
                "":"",
                "":"",
                "":"",
                "":"",
                "":"",
                "":"",
                "":"",
                "":"",
                "":"",
                "":"",
                "":"",
                "":""
            },
            "talent":data.abilities.map(x => 
                {return({
                    "name" : x.ability.name,
                    "hidden": x.is_hidden
                })}),

            "caract": { 
                "masse": "10",
                "capture_rate": "45",
                "generation": "1",
                "egg_group": {
                    "0": "id_egg_group", //Draconique
                    "1": "id_egg_group" //Monstrueuse
                },
                "mf_rate":"45", //45% de male donc (1-mf_rate)% de femelle
                "eff_point": {
                    "stat": "att",
                    "value": "3"
                },
                "poke_familly": "id_familly",
                "xp_10": "1000000"
            },
            "evolution":{
                "howto": "Manière d'évoluer",
                "to":{
                    "0": "id_pokemon",
                    "1": "id_pokemon"
                }
            },
            "lieu":{
                "0": {
                    "name": "name",
                    "precision": "Dans l'eau avec surf",
                    "rate": "rare"
                }, 
                "1": {
                    "name": "name",
                    "precision": "Dans l'eau avec surf",
                    "rate": "rare"
                } 
            },
            "attaque": 
                data.moves.map(x => {
                    return({
                        "name": x.move.name,
                        "level": x.version_group_details[0].level_learned_at
                    })
                }),

            "qr_code": "./Images/pokemon/qr_code/002.png"
        }


        var myJson = JSON.stringify(pokemon)
        console.log(myJson)
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myJson;




}
```

I have no problem to catch the first level of data, but some answers contains this

'''location_area_encounters: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/4/encounters"'''

And this is where it start to be hard for me, How can I get this information in a one shot function?

For you to understand, I put the answer of the API for a pokemon call.

```
abilities: Array(2)
    0: {ability: {…}, is_hidden: true, slot: 3}
    1: {ability: {…}, is_hidden: false, slot: 1}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)

base_experience: 62

forms: Array(1)
    0:
        name: "charmander"
        url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-form/4/"
        __proto__: Object
        length: 1
    __proto__: Array(0)

game_indices: Array(20)
     0: {game_index: 4, version: {…}}
    1: {game_index: 4, version: {…}}
    2: {game_index: 4, version: {…}}
    3: {game_index: 4, version: {…}}
    4: {game_index: 4, version: {…}}
    5: {game_index: 4, version: {…}}
    6: {game_index: 4, version: {…}}
    7: {game_index: 4, version: {…}}
    8: {game_index: 4, version: {…}}
    9: {game_index: 4, version: {…}}
    10: {game_index: 4, version: {…}}
    11: {game_index: 4, version: {…}}
    12: {game_index: 4, version: {…}}
    13: {game_index: 4, version: {…}}
    14: {game_index: 4, version: {…}}
    15: {game_index: 4, version: {…}}
    16: {game_index: 4, version: {…}}
    17: {game_index: 176, version: {…}}
    18: {game_index: 176, version: {…}}
    19: {game_index: 176, version: {…}}
    length: 20
    __proto__: Array(0)

height: 6

held_items: Array(0)
length: 0
__proto__: Array(0)

id: 4

is_default: true

location_area_encounters: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/4/encounters"

moves: Array(93)
0: {move: {…}, version_group_details: Array(4)}
1: {move: {…}, version_group_details: Array(7)}
2: {move: {…}, version_group_details: Array(4)}
3: {move: {…}, version_group_details: Array(18)}
4: {move: {…}, version_group_details: Array(19)}
5: {move: {…}, version_group_details: Array(16)}
6: {move: {…}, version_group_details: Array(4)}
7: {move: {…}, version_group_details: Array(3)}
8: {move: {…}, version_group_details: Array(5)}
9: {move: {…}, version_group_details: Array(2)}
...
length: 93
__proto__: Array(0)

name: "charmander"

order: 5

species:
    name: "charmander"
    url: "ADRESS"
    __proto__: Object

sprites:
    back_default: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/back/4.png"
    back_female: null
    back_shiny: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/back/shiny/4.png"
    back_shiny_female: null
    front_default: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/4.png"
    front_female: null
    front_shiny: "ADRESS"
    front_shiny_female: null
     __proto__: Object

stats: Array(6)
    0: {base_stat: 65, effort: 1, stat: {…}}
    1: {base_stat: 50, effort: 0, stat: {…}}
    2: {base_stat: 60, effort: 0, stat: {…}}
    3: {base_stat: 43, effort: 0, stat: {…}}
    4: {base_stat: 52, effort: 0, stat: {…}}
    5: {base_stat: 39, effort: 0, stat: {…}}
    length: 6
    __proto__: Array(0)

types: Array(1)
    0: {slot: 1, type: {…}}
    length: 1
    __proto__: Array(0)

weight: 85
```

To sum up:

I'd like to create a JSON file that contains all the informations of a pokemon based on the Pokemon API.

I can catch the first level of data, but I can't reach the second level with an API adress in it.

In a next step, I'd like to make a function in my  App that will look at everystart if the answers have changed, and if yes, actualize the document.

Thanks for your help!